# Symfony 3.4 - Sonata - Entity field as Date - Problems

Tags: datetime, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I have a Entity.
I create a field as `Datetime` format

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
private $date;
```

The field in Database is Ok after execute schema update.

This is the mapping to use on Sonata, and show correctly:

```
->add('date', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', [
        'label' => 'admin.entity.community.fields.date.label',
        'required' => true,
        'format' => 'dd/MM/Y',
        'dp_pick_time' => false,
        'dp_use_current' => true,
    ])
```

Select 01/07/2018 on the field. Save
In the DB saved the value: `2017-12-25 00:00:00.000000`

On `preUpdate` i trace the field. The result of the trace:

`object(DateTime)#950 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-12-25 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Madrid" }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just you can edit :

```
->add('date','sonata_type_date_picker',array('label' => 'Date','widget' => 'single_text','format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',))
```

@documentation Sonata-Admin Bundle : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html